# Create login accounts and store them in a text file using php

Tags: php, file, authentication

I want to create a create account page for my simple login site where the user clicks a create account button 
 and they are brought to a page with the following form to enter a login name and a password.

```
<form action = "createaccount.php" method="get">
    <h1> Please enter your information to create a new login account</h1>
    <p>  
        <label>Login Name:</label><input type = "text"  name = "name" />
        <label>Password:</label><input type = "password" name = "pwd" />
        <br/><br/>
    </p>
    <input type = "submit"  id = "submit" value = "submit"/>
    <input type = "reset"  id = "reset" value = "reset"/>
</form>
```

After the user enters there data into the input boxes I want to run a php script to store this data into a text file called `accounts.php` (I know it is not secure but this data has no value to me as i am making it up as part of the learning process).

So far I have the following php code to store the data in the file `createaccount.php`

```
<?php
    $username = $_GET['name'];
    $password = $_GET['pwd'];
    $filename = 'accounts.txt';
    $fp = fopen($filename, 'a+');
    fwrite ($fp, $username . "," . $password . "\n");
    $fclose ($fp);
    echo ("account created");
    header("Location: "login.html"); 
    die();
?>
```

This code I believe should take the inputs from login name and password and store them in a file called `accounts.txt` in the following format

```
username1,password1
username2,password2
etc.
```

then echo the screen `account created` and then take the user to my `login.html` page so they can log in with there new account info.

But I try and run the code and it does not save my data to the file at all and when i submit the form it does not direct me back to the my login screen i just get a message saying page cannot be displayed.

Comment: '... I know it is not secure but nobody but me will see it so security is not an issue ...' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity

Comment: Define 'does not work'. What happens? What doesn't happen? Do you see an error message? What is it?

Comment: You might benefit from reviewing the (free) Register and Login tutorials on phpAcademy.org, [here](https://phpacademy.org/videos/register-login-old) or better yet [here](https://phpacademy.org/videos/oop-loginregister-system)

Comment: No. No. No. NO. Do *not* store user details in a text file. You know it’s not secure, you say so yourself. So don’t do it. What happens if your server’s compromised? Suddenly not just you is seeing that data any more as you thought.

Comment: At LEAST hash & salt the passwords, if you for whatever reason are prevented from using a database (or some other data store that provides authentication) by your requirements.

Comment: @CmdrMoozy i plan on hashing the passwords but i want to get the functionality down before i do that.  But thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this for saving and it works

```
 <?php

 if(isset($_POST['submit_btn']))
 {
  $username = $_POST['name'];
  $password = $_POST['pwd'];
  $text = $username . "," . $password . "\n";
  $fp = fopen('accounts.txt', 'a+');

    if(fwrite($fp, $text))  {
        echo 'saved';

    }
fclose ($fp);    
}

 <form action = "" method="POST">
      <h1> Please enter your information to create a new login account</h1>
        <p>  
          <label>Login Name:</label><input type = "text"  name = "name" />
          <label>Password:</label><input type = "password" name = "pwd" />
          <br/>
          <br/>
        </p>
      <input type = "submit" name="submit_btn" id = "submit" value = "submit"/>
      <input type = "reset"  id = "reset" value = "reset"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: One more thing can you give me an example of an error test to see if a login name is already in use.  Ex. i store login name of paul into the file I want to make sure that no other user can use the name paul because it is already taken  thanks again.

Comment: well you can try something like this: $file = file_get_contents('accounts.txt'); $search = $username.',';
if(strpos($file, $search)) { echo 'name already used'; ... }