# How can I store a users ip address and browser type they're using into a text file using PHP every time they enter invalid login credentials?

Tags: php, html

From my current built login script, how can I store a users ip address and browser type they're using into a text file using PHP every time they enter invalid login credentials on my website?

From looking at this [Create login accounts and store them in a text file using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435348/create-login-accounts-and-store-them-in-a-text-file-using-php) even though my code is different I was trying to apply this to my code, but I couldn't seem to get the PHP to run. As a result, I assumed I messed up the code. I did try utilizing form the post, but didn't have any luck getting it to work in my code.

```
$fp = fopen('accounts.txt', 'a+');
    if(fwrite($fp, $text))  {
        echo 'saved';
    }
```

Login script two page code:

```
<!-- THE FORM -->
<!-- action="index.php" -- This shows where the PHP script that does the processing is located -->
<!-- method="post" -- This aspect  identifies the action that will be performed with the data of the form. For example POST data to the "users" database -->
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <!-- Form/animation -->
    <div class="inner_container text-center animated bounceInDown">
        <!-- Username section -->
        <label><b>Username:</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username:" name="username" required>
        <!-- Password section -->
        <label><b>Password:</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password:" name="password" required>
        <input type="hidden" name="login" value="true">
        <!-- The Login button -->
        <button class="login_button" type="submit">Login <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></button>
        <!-- The button that is linked to the "register.php" page -->
        <a href="register.php">
            <button type="button" class="register_btn">Register <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i></button>
        </a>
        <hr>
        <!-- Help -->
        <a href="https://marketinginsidergroup.com/content-marketing/10-types-online-forms-use/">
            <button type="button" class="register_btn">Help <i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></button>
        </a>
    </div>
</form>
<?php
//Condition, checking the Login button is pressed
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
    //The data from the Form (username & password) is stored into the @$username & @$passwordVariables
    //You use @ before a VARIABLE in PHP when you do not want to initialise the VARIABLE before using it
    @$username=$_POST['username'];
    @$password=$_POST['password'];

    //Statement that will SELECT the data from the "login" table, WHERE the Usename and Password typed match the typed ones
    //Once the database is checked, if login details match than it stores the data in the "$query" VARIABLE
    $query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' and password='$password' ";
    //echo $query;

    //This statement performs both the connection to the database using the values in the "$con" VARIABLE and
    //The SELECT statement stored in the "$query" VARIABLE
    $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    //echo mysql_num_rows($query_run);

    //IF the "$query_run" is run successfully, then
    if($query_run) {
        //Check if the Username and Password exist in the database, if they exist
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        $_SESSION['username'] = $username; //Username handle aspect
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password; //Password handle aspect

        //Sent the user to the "homepage.php" page
        header( "Location: homepage.php");
        }
    }

    //IF the "$query_run" is NOT successful, then
    else {
        //Display this message
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Database Error")</script>';
    }
}

//IF the "$query_run" is NOT successful, then run the below
else {
}
?>
</body>
```

In terms of the browser information I have built this in PHP if it helps. I'm not sure if this applies as I need to store this in the text file.

```
<?php
   function getBrowser()
   {
       $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
       $bname = 'Unknown';
       $platform = 'Unknown';
       $version= "";

       //Fetch platform info 
       if (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
           $platform = 'mac';        //supports mac 
       }
       elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
           $platform = 'windows'; //supports windows 
       }

       // Next get the name of the useragent yes seperately and for good reason
       if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
       {
           $bname = 'Internet Explorer'; //supports IE 
           $ub = "MSIE";
       }
       elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent)) //supports FIREFOX 
       {
           $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox'; 
           $ub = "Firefox";
       }
       elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent))
       {
           $bname = 'Google Chrome'; //supports chrome 
           $ub = "Chrome";
       }
       elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent))
       {
           $bname = 'Apple Safari';
           $ub = "Safari"; //supports safari 
       }


       // finally get the correct version number
       $known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
       $pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) .
       ')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
       if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches)) {
           // we have no matching number just continue
       }

       // see how many we have
       $i = count($matches['browser']);
       if ($i != 1) {
           //we will have two since we are not using 'other' argument yet
           //see if version is before or after the name
           if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub)){
               $version= $matches['version'][0];
           }
           else {
               $version= $matches['version'][1];
           }
       }
       else {
           $version= $matches['version'][0];
       }

       // check if we have a number
       if ($version==null || $version=="") {$version="?";}

       return array(
           'userAgent' => $u_agent,
           'name'      => $bname,
           'version'   => $version,
           'platform'  => $platform,
           'pattern'    => $pattern
       );
   }
   ?>
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <style>
         body {
         background-color: lightblue;
         }
         html, body {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         display: table
         }
         .container {
         display: table-cell;
         text-align: center;
         vertical-align: middle
         }
         .text, .subtext {
         font-weight: bold;
         text-decoration: underline;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body> 
      <!-- NAVBAR -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-bottom animated bounceInRight">
         <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand text-uppercase" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/liam-docherty/">handcrafted BY Liam Docherty <i class="far fa-copyright"></i></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
               <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="http://webbrowserinfo.96.lt">Go back to Homepage <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                     <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                     </a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </nav>
       <!-- STRUCTURE -->
      <div class="container text-center">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <img src="https://toppng.com/public/uploads/preview/browser-icon-android-lollipop-1153095741359wwghidpw.png" class="mx-auto d-block animated bounceInRight" style="width:20%">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
            <?php
               $ua=getBrowser();
               ?>
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-8 text animated bounceInRight" id="content">
               <?php echo "Your browser: {$ua['name']}"; ?>
               <br />
               <?php echo "Version of the browser you're using is : {$ua['version']}"; ?>
               <p class="subtext text-center animated bounceInRight">Thanks for using Liam's browser info script <i class="fas fa-smile-wink"></i></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

In relation to the text file and outputting the errors, I was thinking of using the bootstrap 4 table below I created to store them, however I'm not sure if this is possible.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Username which was used</th>
      <th scope="col">Password which was used</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You are storing plain text password in session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)() function.

```
file_put_contents ( string $filename , mixed $data [, int $flags = 0 [, resource $context ]] ) : int
```

This function is identical to calling fopen(), fwrite() and fclose() successively to write data to a file.

If filename does not exist, the file is created. Otherwise, the existing file is overwritten, unless the FILE_APPEND flag is set.

**Parameters**: 
filename: Path to the file where to write the data.

data : The data to write. Can be either a string, an array or a stream resource.

If data is a stream resource, the remaining buffer of that stream will be copied to the specified file. This is similar with using stream_copy_to_stream().

You can also specify the data parameter as a single dimension array. This is equivalent to file_put_contents($filename, implode('', $array)).

flags : The value of flags can be any combination of the following flags, joined with the binary OR (|) operator.

in your case what you can do is :

```
file_put_contents("/path/of/file/to/store/data" , print_R($ua , true) , FILE_APPEND);
```

or

```
file_put_contents("/path/of/file/to/store/data" , json_encode($ua) , FILE_APPEND);
```